# How to make specific custom table data searchable in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, search

I just created custom module with name  `example` , And it has a form to enter data to it's specific  custom table. 
I want to make the data in this custom table searchable with Drupal default search feature.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I already skimmed through the Drupal api docs and followed the instruction but I couldn't make it working.

Comment: If you want more detailed advice you need to provide some more information about what you are trying to achieve, but first look at the the API for the core search module which is documented here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/group/search/7

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong I searched with keywords inside my custom table. And 1not showing in the search results. In another words how can I instruct Drupal to search my custom table too while a search query is executing.

Comment: Have you read the API docs and implemented the hooks? If so, please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal search interface manages a global search mechanism.

Modules may plug into this system to provide searches of different types of
data. Most of the system is handled by search.module, so this must be enabled
for all of the search features to work.

There are three ways to interact with the search system:

- Specifically for searching nodes, you can implement
  hook_node_update_index() and hook_node_search_result(). However, note that
  the search system already indexes all visible output of a node; i.e.,
  everything displayed normally by hook_view() and hook_node_view(). This is
  usually sufficient. You should only use this mechanism if you want
  additional, non-visible data to be indexed.
- Implement hook_search_info(). This will create a search tab for your module
  on the /search page with a simple keyword search form. You will also need
  to implement hook_search_execute() to perform the search.
- Implement hook_update_index(). This allows your module to use Drupal's
  HTML indexing mechanism for searching full text efficiently.

If your module needs to provide a more complicated search form, then you need
to implement it yourself without hook_search_info(). In that case, you should
define it as a local task (tab) under the /search page (e.g. /search/mymodule)
so that users can easily find it.

The full documentation can be found  at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/group/search/7